# Redirect SSL requests from proxy Apache server to another Apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, apache-2.4, proxy, https

We have a legacy application with URL `https://www2.devDocApp.com/`  which is running on `Ubuntu8` and `apache2.2` with no TLS 1.2 support, we had hardtime upgrading `apache2.2` and openSSL on Ubuntu 8 box, so now we are standing proxy `apache` server (`secure-devDocApp` windows 2012 VM with Apache/2.4.29 (Win64)) which redirects all the requests to `https://www2.devDocApp.com/`

Below is the apache configuration I've used to set up proxy server `secure-devDocApp`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload" 
DocumentRoot "C:/apache/htdocs"
ServerName  secure-devDocApp    
SSLEngine on
RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS"


SSLProtocol -ALL TLSv1.2
SSLCertificateFile "C:/apache/conf/server.cer"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/apache/conf/server.key"   
SSLCACertificateFile "C:/apache/conf/ca.cer"
SSLVerifyClient optional
SSLVerifyDepth  3

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "C:/apache/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>    
ProxyPass   / https://www2.devDocApp.com/   
SSLProxyEngine on

RequestHeader set X_SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL "%{SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL}s"
RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO "https" env=HTTPS
RequestHeader set SslSubject "%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}s"

</VirtualHost>
```

We have a page '/clientAuth' which requires client certificate authentication, so When am hitting the proxy apache URL `https://secure-devDocApp/clientAuth` in browser it is prompting to choose from an existing  client certificates, but when I choose the client certificate am getting a 404 instead of authorized content, however client certificate authentication works fine on the legacy URL https://www2.devDocApp.com/clientAuth` which prompts for client certificate and I can see the authorized page for the chosen client certificate.

I suspect proxy apache server `secure-devDocApp` is not forwarding the SSL certificate requests to the legacy apache server of `www2.devDocApp.com`. Can someone please help me forwarding SSL requests from one apache server to another?

Comment: You cannot forward the original client certificate but only information collected about the client certificate. This what you do in the config you show by setting various request headers based on the client certificate for the request to your legacy server. Only, I suspect that your legacy server expects the real client certificate and does not care about the request headers you set. While this is just a guess since not enough is known about your legacy server, it would explain the behavior you see.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Ho do I verify that my legacy apache is expecting actual client cert or just the ssl headers?

Comment: Look at the configuration of Apache and the code of your application. If Apache is requesting a client certificate (i.e.  `SSLVerifyClient`) and/or your application is not looking at the specific HTTP headers you've set for information about the client then you did it wrong. This means that you very likely need to adapt both the config of the legacy server and also the code of your legacy application to work without direct access to the client certificates.

Answer (score 0):

In our legacy `apache` updated `RequestHeader set X_SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL "%{SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL}s"` to below, to allow Client Certificate authentication via proxy apache server

```
SetEnvIf X_SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL "^$" NO_X_SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL
RequestHeader set X_SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL "%{SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL}s" env=NO_X_SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL
```

Also added `SSLOptions +ExportCertData` to proxy apache `VirtualHost`